# Using iPhoneX whole screen area without XCode 9 and iOS 11 Base SDK

Tags: xcode8, ios10, iphone-x

When iphone 4 was released, it had a different aspect ratio than previous devices and the old apps used to run in compatibility mode with top and bottom black area letterboxing. 
One was able to fix it by simply adding a 320x568 size png file with name Default-568h.png.
No new SDK was required.

Is it possible to do the same for iPhoneX ?

After trying all Launch screen storyboard approach, I have tried adding Default-812h@3x.png and different variants of it but none seems to be working. Have anyone succeeded in making a base SDK 10 build run fullscreen on iPhoneX ?